# .htaccess frustration with subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

Under the **Zend Framework,** I have a directory structure like this:

**Index: /domains/example.com/public_html/public/index.php**

**Blog index: /domains/example.com/public_html/blog/index.php**

In my .htaccess file, shown below is the piece that points to the homepage - this works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

I have enabled a subdomain in my host admin control panel and now I want to add a blog which is accessible via: blog.example.com

I tried adding:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} = ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule /blog/(.*) http://blog\.example\.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} = ^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /blog/index.php [L]
```

but this produces a dreaded "*Internal Server Error - 500*" when navigating to blog.example.com, example.com/blog and even example.com..

I suspect that it could be a complication with the Zend Framework that's causing grief.
What should I add / edit in .htaccess for blog.example.com to point correctly ?

Please & thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blog\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/blog%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,RSA]
```

This will rewrite all your blog.example.com traffic to example.com/blog

Comment: Shikhar, as I understand what you did there is point blog.example.com traffic to example.com? I want to point blog.example.com traffic to  /domains/example.com/public_html/blog/index.php right?

Comment: have modified the answer to suit your need. Tell me if this works for you.

Comment: Hi again Shikhar. Again I believe you misunderstand the question. For now, let's not worry about anything to do between blog.example.com and example.com/blog. I simply want to get blog.example.com pointing to the the blog index page in directory structure which I stated.

Comment: Oh, then simply create a blog symlink(http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uln.htm) in blog.example.com htdocs, to point to example.com's htdoc's blog. So when you point to blog.example.com/blog/index.php you will be actually fetching example.com/blog/index.php